# Cascade deleting - Tree Structure - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with cascade deleting. Here is my TreeStructure project - my entities:

Node:

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NodeId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentNodeId")]
    public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
    public List<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
    public List<Leaf> SubLeaves { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        SubNodes = new List<Node>();
        SubLeaves = new List<Leaf>();
    }
}
```

Leaf:

```
public class Leaf
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LeafId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentNodeId")]
    public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the additional connections:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(cat => cat.SubNodes)
            .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(cat => cat.SubLeaves)
            .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode);
```

The problem occurs when I try delete node, which has subnodes. On response I get:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_Nodes_Nodes_ParentNodeId". The conflict occurred in database "TreeV3", table "dbo.Nodes", column 'ParentNodeId'.

So I decided to add `OnDelete` behavior in the fluent api:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(cat => cat.SubNodes)
            .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
            .HasMany(cat => cat.SubLeaves)
            .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

But when I run app. I get exception:

> **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Nodes_Nodes_ParentNodeId' on table 'Nodes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I think it happens because ParentNodeId in Node entity is set on "can be null"

```
public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
```

But I can't resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you need to change **DeleteBehavior** from `Cascade` to `NoAction`.

This shows that if you want to delete a parent node that contains child nodes, you cannot delete the parent node. You must manually delete all child nodes to delete the parent node.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
              .HasMany(cat => cat.SubNodes)
              .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
                .HasMany(cat => cat.SubLeaves)
                .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-3.1).

Comment: But I want to have cascade deleting because I want to make a mechanism that is in any structure with files, i.e. when I delete a folder, they are also deleted under folders and files

Comment: @KrystianWolański, as your `Node` table contains a one-to-many relationship to `itself`, this cannot be achieved with `Cascade` in ef core.
So you have two options, one is to redesign the table, convert the one-to-many Node table with itself into another new table, `similar to Leaf table`. The other is by getting `ParentNodeId foreign key` value when deleting, then manually delete related subdata through code.