# EF Core: Is it possible to cascade remove self-referencing objects from database without in-code recursion

Tags: sql-server

I have self-referencing **Directory** object. Each directory have parent and list of childs.

Modelbuilder configuration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Directory>()
            .HasMany(d => d.Directories).WithOne(p => p.Parent).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Gives me a following exception on migration:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_DirectoryReference_DirectoryReference_ParentId' on table 'DirectoryReference' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'

I know how to delete my directories by recursion, but if it possible I would like SQL Server to handle this process by cascade delete.

Is it even possible?

Comment: *"if it possible i would like SQL Server to handle this process by cascade delete::* If you haven't noticed, the exception is raised by SQL Server, so... that should answer your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044608/cascade-deleting-tree-structure-entity-framework

Comment: It is easy to help you, If you can post the entity classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public async Task DeleteDirectory(int idDirectory, DbContext dbContext)
{
    var directory = await dbContext.Directories.FindAsync(idDirectory);
    if (directory == null)
        return;
        
    var toDelete = new List<Directory>();
    toDelete.Add(directory);

    var subDirs = await dbContext.Directories
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == directory.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
    while (subDirs.Count > 0)
    {
        toDelete.AddRange(subDirs);
        var lastIds = subDirs.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
        subDirs = await dbContext.Komentare
            .Where(x => lastIds.Contains(x.ParentId))
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    toDelete.Reverse();
    dbContext.Directories.RemoveRange(toDelete);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```